# Pumping Lemma's Condition 3 concept

Tags: computation, pumping-lemma

I'm following one of the examples from my textbook on the Pumping Lemma:

```
Let C = {w | w has an equal number of 0s and 1s}

Condition 3 stipulates: |xy| <= p



If |xy| <= p, then y must consist only of 0s, so xyyz is not in C. 
Therefore s cannot be pumped
```

I'm having trouble understanding how condition 3 leads to the conclusion that "y must only consist of 0s, so xyyz is not in C"

Comment: If you could add a few preceding lines from the book, it would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the string chosen is 0<sup>p</sup>1<sup>p</sup>.
Since |xy| <= p, and xyz = 0<sup>p</sup>1<sup>p</sup>, the string xy will be 0<sup>k</sup> where k <= p since the first p symbols of 0<sup>p</sup>1<sup>p</sup> are all 0's. Since xy consists of only 0's, y must also consist of only 0's

And learn to put your question in a proper manner. You cannot expect others to "predict" your question while you put half of the information

Comment: Hi the string chosen was indeed 0p1p thank you I understand it now